# The onCreate,Bundle,ListView ,etc all the methods that i have used in below code is giving me an error.Is there any mistake in my xml file?

Tags: android, xml

```
package com.example.perfect.listofproduct;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView ProductListView;

List<Product> products;

ProductAdapter productAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ProductListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productListView);
    products = new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("I-Phone 7","Gadget",101,14000));
    products.add(new Product("MacBook Pro","Gadget",102,99000));
    products.add(new Product("2-States","Book",103,180));
    products.add(new Product("2-States","Movie",104,100));
    products.add(new Product("Hoodie","Clothes",105,400));

    productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this,products);
    ProductListView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: It is solved by reinstalling all the things of android studio and it works fine.